# Using an interface to apply method to ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'm reviewing for an exam. A question on an old test was to: Using an interface, write a method that applies an arbitrary method to every element of an ArrayList. Both the arraylist and method are the parameters to the method.

Would a workable solution be:

```
public <object> someMethod() {
    scanner GLaDOS = new (someArray);
    someArray.useDelimiter(",");
    for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        someOtherMethod(someArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact question from the test? It's not very clear, IMO.

Comment: @Andrew, yes that's all it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would've expected something like this:

```
// define the interface to represent an arbitrary function
interface Function<T> {
    void Func(T el);
}

// now the method to apply an arbitrary function to the list
<T> void applyFunctionToArrayList(ArrayList<T> list, Function<T> func){
    // iterate over the list
    for(T item : list){
        // invoke the "arbitrary" function
        func.Func(item);
    }
}
```

---

It's ambiguous in the question, but this might mean returning a new ArrayList, so this might be another acceptable answer

```
// define the interface to represent an arbitrary function
interface Function<T> {
    T Func(T el);
}

// now the method to apply an arbitrary function to the list
<T> ArrayList<T> applyFunctionToArrayList(ArrayList<T> list, Function<T> func){
    ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();

    // iterate over the list
    for(T item : list){
        // invoke the "arbitrary" function
        newList.add(func.Func(item));
    }
}
```

On a side note, you would then, say, invoke the application like (for example, doubling every number in the list):

```
ArrayList<Double> list = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
ArrayList<Double> doubledList = applyFunctionToArrayList(list, 
  new Function<Double>{
    Double Func(Double x){
        return x * 2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your method could give back a new ArrayList of the results.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: it could but the question asked for application to every array element, I'll update nonetheless.

Comment: thanks! This looks good, I'll see if the prof says it's what he was looking for.

Comment: I think the Function interface should be 
interface Function<T, R> {
    R Func(T el);
}